# Later 'if' condition getting called before the 'alert' message in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Pardon me for the vague description

**C# Code:**

```
if(listCount <= minCountRequired)
{
    DisplayError(errMsgForLessCount); // Calls scriptmanager to display alert.
}

if(!ConfirmFromUser)  // asks for User confirmation to continue... getting called first  
{
     //perform some actions... not imp...
}
```

*Method ConfirmFromUser*

```
private bool ConfirmFromUser
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if(confirmValue == "Yes")
          return true;
    else
          return false;
}
```

**Issue:** The 2nd 'if' condition is getting called first while execution of the web page. By that I don't mean the contents inside the 2nd if, just the condition... 
Statements inside first if condition is getting executed later than the 2nd IF condition.

**Problem ?** Is the problem that the first uses Javascript to display alert and that we are calling that using the ScriptManager and the later is Request.Form?
Kind of consistency issue???

Comment: Should the second if be executed only if the first one is true?

Comment: what happens when you set breakpoints and step through the code..? please tell us.? also that is the value of `listCount && minCountRequired`

Comment: 2nd one should be executed only when first one is false.. there are more else if related to the 2nd if that's why I didn't keep it as else... Values for listCount if less than 2 should display error message.....The control is not even going to the first if,2nd if's confirm box is coming before event is triggered

Answer (score 2):

Your C# code is executing in order. The ASP.NET server is generating the JavaScript and HTML that will be executed in a user's web browser. It will generate *all* of the output and send it to the client. Then the client can do whatever it wants with that data.

So, if your C# code generates some output that looks like this:

```
<html><body><script>alert('hi')</script><b>Hello!
```

The entire contents of this document will be sent to the client. The client will receive the entire document, and begin to execute it. This isn't Pee-Wee's Playhouse—neither C# nor the web browser will stop the data transfer just because the magic word `alert()` appeared in the output.

Here's a sequence diagram of what is going on. Note that there is no part in the middle where the client and server continue to communicate -- **in HTTP, once the request is over, that's it!** You have to make another request (e.g. using AJAX, forms, links, etc.) to get more data to the server.

[image: Sequence diagram of the HTTP lifecycle]